# replacing iframe for improving SEO

Tags: iframe, seo

My site was written a long time ago using iframe.

In addition, all pages include the following javascript code, in order to prevent direct browsing of the frame's content:

```
if (top.location == self.location) {  
    top.location = "http://example.com/index.html";  
}
```

Does this design damage SEO? If so, what should I do instead?
Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid iframes at all costs for effective site SEO.

Start afresh, re-code all pages with fresh URLs. make sure iframes are not used at all unless you absolutely need to pull content from external sources

Comment: Thanks.  I use iframes with my own content solely. The reason I use it is to have a fixed menu, as well as fixed top and bottom of the page. So what is the best way to achieve it without iframes? Should I duplicate the code of the menu, top and bottom and have it all reloaded with every click on a menu item?

Comment: I'll just mention that I have read about more sophisticated things that could replace the iframes, like using Ajax, or the object tag, but I don't know if that's what fits here, and if that's good for SEO.

Comment: You can replicate the menu code (header and footer) across your new pages. Use HTML/CSS or pure CSS that can be inserted in each page using DIVs to maintain consistency and to avoid editing code on every page (as and when you may need to do so). Always remember that when a SE lands on your page, it reads code, not design, so ensure a maximum of your on-page code is what you want your website indexed for against that URL. iframes provides a disparity between your site content and URL

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about SEO, do NOT use frames.